# Trying to make sqsh with FreeTDS

Tags: installation, centos, compile

I am trying to install sqsh on a CentOS Linux box on which I have successfully installed FreeTDS in `/opt/freetds`. I set the SYBASE variable to /opt/freetds.

Configure runs and has this to say about Open Client:

```
checking Open Client installation... /opt/freetds 
checking Open Client libraries...
checking Open Client needs net libraries... no (version FreeTDS) 
checking Open Client OS libraries... -ldl -lm
```

When the make runs it seems to do OK until it throws up a bunch of errors like this:

```
sqsh_init.o: In function `sqsh_exit':
 /opt/sqsh-2.4/src/sqsh_init.c:332: undefined reference to `ct_close'
 /opt/sqsh-2.4/src/sqsh_init.c:333: undefined reference to `ct_close'
 /opt/sqsh-2.4/src/sqsh_init.c:334: undefined reference to `ct_con_drop'
 /opt/sqsh-2.4/src/sqsh_init.c:340: undefined reference to `ct_exit'
 /opt/sqsh-2.4/src/sqsh_init.c:341: undefined reference to `ct_exit'
 /opt/sqsh-2.4/src/sqsh_init.c:356: undefined reference to `cs_ctx_drop'
```

Nothing I've been able to find on the internet has been of any help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

UGH!  I had the same problem.  Go into src/Makefile in the sqsh directory and make sure you have the correct SYBASE_LIBS:

SYBASE_LIBS = -lct -lsybdb -lsybdb -ltdsodbc

or something appropriate for your platform.  The ones I have there are what I had to put in to get it to build.  Apparently the Makefile is created automatically by configure and it didn't do such an awesome job on the CentOS platform.

HTH.

-jamil